# Generate all combinations of 2 lists (game playing)

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am trying to generate all possible combinations between 2 lists A and B in python with a few constraints. A and B alternate in picking values, A always picks first. A and B may have overlapping values. If A has already picked a value, then B cannot pick it, and vice versa.

Both lists need not be of equal lengths. If one list has no available values to pick then I stop generating combinations

Also the elements picked by each must be in increasing order, i.e. `A[1] < A[2] < .... A[n]` and `B[1] < B[2] < .... B[n]` where `A[i]` and `B[i]` is the `i`-th element picked by A and B respectively

Example:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4]
B = [2, 5]
```

Solution I need is

```
(1), (2), (3), (4),
(1,2), (1,5), (2,5), (3,2), (3,5), (4,2), (4,5),
(1,2,3), (1,2,4), (3,2,4), (1,5,2), (1,5,3), (1,5,4), (2,5,3), (2,5,4), (3,5,4),
(1,2,3,5), (1,2,4,5), (3,2,4,5)
(1,2,3,5,4)
```

I believe itertools in python can be useful for this but I havent really figured out how to implement it for this case.

As of now, this is how I am solving it:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4]
B = [2, 5]
A_set = set(A)
B_set = set(b)
#Append both sets
C = A.union(B)
for L in range(len(C), 0, -1):
        for subset in itertools.combinations(C, L):
        #Check if subset meets constraints and print it if it does
```

Comment: Show your code in your question :)

Comment: This sounds like such a weird way to pick combinations that there might not be something in itertools that does it.

Comment: OTOH I've seen people do some amazing things with the existing functions it has.

Comment: I think a recursive function is the right way to do this.

Comment: "A and B may have overlapping values." Is there a missing "not"?

Comment: @Acccumulation The input may have overlapping values

Comment: @Barmar I thought of appending set A to set B, then generating all possible combinations with itertools, and then checking the subsets which match my constraints. Looking for a better way to implement it though

Comment: You seem to be using A and B to refer both to the inputs and the people choosing numbers from them, which is confusing. Also, I take the people can stop picking numbers, even if there are available values?

Comment: @Jack That will definitely not work, since it won't alternate between them.

Comment: Try to think about how you worked it out when you wrote the desired result. Then translate that into code.

Comment: @Acccumulation Yes that is correct

Comment: @Barmar Okay, will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in comments, this is probably much too specific to be easily solved using itertools, and you should use a recursive (generator) function instead. Just pick the next element from whichever list's turn it is, keeping track of the elements already selected, and recursively call the function again, swapping and shortening the lists and adding the element to the set of selected elements, until you've got the required number.

Something like this (this might be improved by adding parameters for the current index in both lists instead of actually slicing the lists for the recursive calls):

```
def solve(n, lst1, lst2, selected):
    if n == 0:
        yield []
    elif lst1:
        for i, x in enumerate(lst1):
            if x not in selected:
                selected.add(x)
                for rest in solve(n-1, lst2, lst1[i+1:], selected):
                    yield [x] + rest
                selected.remove(x)
```

Or a bit more condensed:

```
def solve(n, lst1, lst2, selected):
    if n == 0:
        yield []
    elif lst1:
        yield from ([x] + rest for i, x in enumerate(lst1) if x not in selected
                               for rest in solve(n-1, lst2, lst1[i+1:], selected.union({x})))
```

Example:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4]
B = [2, 5]
result = [res for n in range(1, len(A)+len(B)+1) for res in solve(n, A, B, set())]
```

Afterwards, `result` is:

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4],
 [1, 2], [1, 5], [2, 5], [3, 2], [3, 5], [4, 2], [4, 5],
 [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 5, 2], [1, 5, 3], [1, 5, 4], [2, 5, 3], [2, 5, 4], [3, 2, 4], [3, 5, 4], 
 [1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 4, 5], [3, 2, 4, 5],
 [1, 2, 3, 5, 4]]
```

Comment: Thanks. This does exactly what i want